# Debian: get package name for installed file

Tags: debian, kernel, dpkg, header-file

I'm connected via SSH to a PC running Linux kernel 3.11.1:

```
root@alix:~# uname -r
3.11.1
```

how can I find out which package installed this specific file or kernel version respectively?

I tried

```
root@alix:/boot# dpkg -S vmlinuz-3.11.1 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *vmlinuz-3.11.1*
```

Other installed kernel versions can be found with **dpkg -S**:

```
root@alix:/boot# dpkg -S vmlinuz-3.2.23
linux-image-3.2.23-ath5kmod: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.23-ath5kmod
```

My purpose: I would like to install the corresponding Linux headers for version 3.11.1 to compile a kernel module for it. **apt-cache search linux-headers** lists 15 different header versions but not that one for 3.11.1.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list every installed package with `dpkg -l` and filter through the results with `grep` for the kernel packages

```
dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image'
dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image' | grep '3.11'
```

To find the kernel headers package for your running kernel:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: I tried that before. **dpkg -l | grep "linux-image"** lists the following packages: linux-image-3.2.0-3-486, linux-image-3.2.23, linux-image-3.2.23-ath5kmod, 3.2.23-ath5kmod-10.00.Custom, linux-image-486 But package for kernel 3.11.1 is missing. Therefore, I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Not sure why the package isn't coming up.  See my updated answer to  find the headers for your running kernel

Comment: The problem is that there is also no correct header for the version 3.11.1. Is a "meta-package" responsible for installing the kernel version 3.11.1? For instance, "linux-image-486" is listed as meta-package.

Comment: I guess this PC is pretty misconfigured and now I have to clean up this mess. :(

Comment: Here's a [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/kernel-3-11-1-released-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/) for installing the deb packages for 3.11.1, but I would personally stick with a kernel that's supported by the package manager

Comment: Thanks Creek. Personally, I also prefer the kernels provided by the package manager, but I will give your link a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

My original problem was that there were no appropriate kernel headers available for the currently installed Linux kernel (3.11.1).

Finally, I solved this issue in four steps:

1. Removed the kernels which were installed via **apt-get**.
2. Removed custom kernels:

   - /boot/vmlinuz*KERNEL-VERSION*
   - /boot/initrd*KERNEL-VERSION*
   - /boot/System-map*KERNEL-VERSION*
   - /boot/config-*KERNEL-VERSION*
   - /lib/modules/*KERNEL-VERSION*/
   - See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-redhat-linux-delete-kernel-command/) for a detailed description.
3. Installed kernel **and** corresponding headers which are shipped per default by package manager **apt-get** (it's version 3.2.0-4-486).
4. Update grub via **update-grub**.

Now, I can compile and use the required Linux kernel module. Thanks Creek to point me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [dlocate(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dlocate/dlocate.1.en.html) command from [dlocate](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/dlocate) package:

```
$ dlocate /boot/vmlinuz-*
linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-7-amd64: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-7-amd64
```

`dlocate` takes file name as an argument and returns name of the package that owns/provides given file.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install linux-headers` should get you the headers for all installed kernels